# adding controls to a subview of an IBDesignable view

Tags: swift, cocoa, interface-builder

Suppose I'm working in Interface Builder and I create an IBDesignable view called `A`. `A` contains a subview called `B`. I would like the ability to simply drag controls onto `B` in Interface Builder and have them appropriately added as children of `B`, but it looks like Interface Builder only wants me to work with `A`. Is there a way to tell `A` to instead add new subviews/controls to `B`, or to tell Interface Builder that `B` should be the "active" view?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this (I think) where I wanted the subview for my custom view to be showing up in Interface Builder so that I could hook up my outlets and actions. After searching around a bit, I realised that you can do this by building an XIB file (essentially designing the custom UI in IB and associating it with a code file, then loading that as a nib into your main storyboard).

I followed this tutorial to get my custom subviews showing up in my main storyboard: [IBDesignable UIView subclass from XIB tutorial](http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6).

Once in your main storyboard, you can see the custom view as a discrete unit (ie. not showing the subview hierarchy like you would see for a stack view, for example). But visually it shows up looking just like what you expect, and the outlets and actions gets hooked up between the XIB file and your code.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there appears to be no way to change the view Interface builder uses as the view your custom control wants. It isn't possible to set the drag and drop destination to subview "B" ... More problems, The UIView "A" isn't the target either. Interface builder adds drag and dropped controls to the UIView beneath your custom view. When you instance a custom view in interface builder their is a UIView beneath it. That view is the one used.

It is obviously possible to do what you'd like to do. You can explore this by dragging a UITableViewCell onto your project. The cell exposes a subview recognized by Interface Builder.

Either programmatically, without a nib, a custom UIView or or a custom UIView with a nib, both have a parent UIView that Interface builds lays out controls on. During debug you can see the layers created, and also present at runtime.